# Using variables in stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I am using Microsoft SQL server and writing a stored procedure that contains many select statements. Here I want two variables that hold results of two select statements, and I want to add those two variables to get final result. Please help me doing this (syntax and example).

Answer (score 2):

Below is the syntax for SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @UserEmail Varchar(250)
DECLARE @LoginID INT 

SET @UserEmail  = 'a@b.org'

select @LoginID = LoginID from Login L
Where L.UserEmail = @UserEmail
```

Answer (score 2):

You should clarify which DB you are using. In MS SQL Server, you can use temporary table variable like this:

```
BEGIN

SELECT product_id,product_name INTO #temp1 FROM products;

SELECT product_id,product_name INTO #temp2 FROM products;

SELECT * FROM #temp1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM #temp2;

END
```

There are several types of temporary table variable in MS SQL Server.I've used one of them.To know more about this, just search "MS SQL Server Temporary tables" in web.

EDIT:
Here is another example with another type of temporary table variable in MS SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @temp1 TABLE (product_id INT,product_name VARCHAR(100));

    DECLARE @temp2 TABLE (product_id INT,product_name VARCHAR(100));

    INSERT INTO @temp1 SELECT product_id,product_name FROM products WHERE cat_id=1;

    INSERT INTO @temp2 SELECT product_id,product_name FROM products WHERE cat_id=2;

    SELECT product_id,product_name
    FROM @temp1
    UNION
    SELECT product_id,product_name
    FROM @temp2;
```

Comment: I am using MIcrosoft SQL server

Comment: That sql query is for MS SQL Server. #temp1,#temp2 are 2 temporary table variables which store two sql statement result sets. did not that sql query clear to you?